# How to set up automatic script launch on MacOS?

Tags: python, bash, macos, cron, launchd

I'm not a programmer, so I went to solve my problem in ChatGPT. The task is this: create a script that will automatically create a screenshot of the entire screen on MacOS every 2 minutes, save them to a folder on your hard drive, and then upload them to a folder on Google Drive. Using ChatGPT, a bash script was created that creates a screenshot and calls a python script that uploads the screenshot to Google Drive.

What is the problem: the script works fine when run manually, but does not run automatically. Although I configured cron first and then launchd, both of these methods do not work.

Here is a bash script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Переход в директорию скрипта
cd "/Users/evgenijserikov/Script Screenshots"

# Путь к скрытой папке для сохранения скриншотов
screenshot_dir="$HOME/.hidden_screenshots"

# Создать папку, если она не существует
mkdir -p "$screenshot_dir"

# Создать уникальное имя файла для скриншота с датой, временем, именем приложения и названием веб-страницы или диалога/группы в Telegram
timestamp=$(date +"%H:%M_%d-%m-%Y")
app_name=$(osascript -e 'tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to name as text')

# Получить название вкладки в Google Chrome или название диалога/группы в Telegram, если соответствующее приложение открыто
if [ "$app_name" = "Google Chrome" ]; then
    window_title=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Google Chrome" to get title of active tab of front window')
elif [ "$app_name" = "Telegram" ]; then
    telegram_dialog=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Telegram" to return name of the front chat of front window' 2>/dev/null)
fi

# Создать имя файла с учетом названия вкладки или диалога/группы (если есть)
if [ -n "$window_title" ]; then
    screenshot_file="$screenshot_dir/${timestamp}_${app_name}_${window_title}.png"
elif [ -n "$telegram_dialog" ]; then
    screenshot_file="$screenshot_dir/${timestamp}_${app_name}_${telegram_dialog}.png"
else
    screenshot_file="$screenshot_dir/${timestamp}_${app_name}.png"
fi

# Сделать скриншот всего экрана и сохранить в файл
screencapture -x "$screenshot_file"

# Загрузить скриншот на Google Drive
python3 upload_to_drive.py "$screenshot_file"

# Удалить скриншоты старше 48 часов из локальной папки
find "$screenshot_dir" -name "*.png" -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
```

Here is a python script code:

```
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

# Путь к файлу скриншота передается как аргумент
screenshot_file_path = sys.argv[1]

# ID вашей папки на Google Drive
folder_id = '18W_MZKixax-xmgcwnSbFzm301C_4BXed'

# Загрузка сохраненных учетных данных
credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('/Users/evgenijserikov/Script Screenshots/token.json')

# Инициализация сервиса Google Drive
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Вычисление времени 48 часов назад в формате ISO 8601 с учетом часового пояса UTC
time_48_hours_ago = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=48)
formatted_time = time_48_hours_ago.isoformat()

# Получение и удаление старых файлов из Google Drive
files = service.files().list(q=f"'{folder_id}' in parents and modifiedTime < '{formatted_time}'",
                             fields='files(id, name)').execute().get('files', [])

for file in files:
    service.files().delete(fileId=file['id']).execute()

# Создание метаданных файла
file_metadata = {
    'name': screenshot_file_path.split('/')[-1],
    'parents': [folder_id]
}

# Загрузка файла
media = MediaFileUpload(screenshot_file_path)
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

print(f"File ID: {file.get('id')}")
```

Here is a crontab line:

```
*/2 * * * * /Users/evgenijserikov/ScriptScreenshots/screenshot_script.sh
```

Here is a .plist code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.screenshot</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/evgenijserikov/Script\ Screenshots/screenshot_script.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>120</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Can you help me to solve a problem?

MacOS Sonoma 14.1 (MacBook Pro M1 PRO). Can you help me to solve a problem?

Comment: Make sure you've given `cron` full disk access.

Comment: Some interesting statistics at https://techxplore.com/news/2023-08-chatgpt-showdown-stack.html on code generated by ChatGPT: "Researchers said that 52% of 512 ChatGPT responses to questions were incorrect. Disconcertingly, among the responses preferred by test participants, 77% were wrong.". So YMMV using that as a starting point.

Comment: In the privacy settings I opened full disk access for cron and crontab

Comment: I don't think this can work from crontab, since cron jobs don't run in the same context as the GUI session and won't have access to it to take the screenshot. Making it a launch agent (*not* a launch daemon) should solve this, but then you need to give it the relevant privacy permission (see [this AskDifferent question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338213/how-to-run-a-launchagent-that-runs-a-script-which-causes-failures-because-of-sys)).

Comment: Maybe you could run it as a *"Login Item"* instead of using `cron` then it would presumably have access to your GUI session as pointed out by @GordonDavisson. You would just have to wrap it in a forever loop along with a `sleep 120` to fire it every 2 minutes.

Comment: Which part was failing and in what way? You need to do some debugging. Do you get error messages on cron? At the very least, put a `set -x` into your script and analyze the stderr you got.